# animate a header color line as a loop CSS3

Tags: html, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to put a 100% color ribbon into the header of my website, similar to: http://mightyslider.com/
The color ribbon in the header is using simple css style that has all the info, colors, div position etc. I can create a color ribbon similar to this but it does not animate? Is there something out there jquery or CSS3 that is similar to it?

html:

```
<div id="header-colors"></div>
```

css:

```
#header-colors {
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-direction: reverse;
    animation-duration: 15s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: header-colors;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left center , #f5aa00 0px, #f5aa00 12.5%, #55c5e9 12.5%, #55c5e9 25%, #6b3a78 25%, #6b3a78 37.5%, #9e1c32 37.5%, #9e1c32 50%, #0768bf 50%, #0768bf 62.5%, #629db1 62.5%, #629db1 75%, #f5aa00 75%, #f5aa00 87.5%, #55c5e9 87.5%, #55c5e9 100%);
    background-size: 100% auto;
    height: 10px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine?

Look at this jsfiddle I just made.

http://jsfiddle.net/89BuE/2/

HTML:

CSS:

```
#header-colors {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 10px;
width: 100%;
background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,0 50%,100% 50%,color-stop(0,#e75239),color-stop(12.5%,#e75239),color-stop(12.5%,#ff961c),color-stop(25%,#ff961c),color-stop(25%,#ffcc27),color-stop(37.5%,#ffcc27),color-stop(37.5%,#fce62f),color-stop(50%,#fce62f),color-stop(50%,#cde35b),color-stop(62.5%,#cde35b),color-stop(62.5%,#82cc33),color-stop(75%,#82cc33),color-stop(75%,#41bece),color-stop(87.5%,#41bece),color-stop(87.5%,#049cdb),color-stop(100%,#049cdb));
background-image:-moz-gradient(linear,0 50%,100% 50%,color-stop(0,#e75239),color-stop(12.5%,#e75239),color-stop(12.5%,#ff961c),color-stop(25%,#ff961c),color-stop(25%,#ffcc27),color-stop(37.5%,#ffcc27),color-stop(37.5%,#fce62f),color-stop(50%,#fce62f),color-stop(50%,#cde35b),color-stop(62.5%,#cde35b),color-stop(62.5%,#82cc33),color-stop(75%,#82cc33),color-stop(75%,#41bece),color-stop(87.5%,#41bece),color-stop(87.5%,#049cdb),color-stop(100%,#049cdb));
background-image: gradient(linear,0 50%,100% 50%,color-stop(0,#e75239),color-stop(12.5%,#e75239),color-stop(12.5%,#ff961c),color-stop(25%,#ff961c),color-stop(25%,#ffcc27),color-stop(37.5%,#ffcc27),color-stop(37.5%,#fce62f),color-stop(50%,#fce62f),color-stop(50%,#cde35b),color-stop(62.5%,#cde35b),color-stop(62.5%,#82cc33),color-stop(75%,#82cc33),color-stop(75%,#41bece),color-stop(87.5%,#41bece),color-stop(87.5%,#049cdb),color-stop(100%,#049cdb));
 -webkit-animation: headercolors 15s linear 0s infinite;
animation: headercolors 15s linear 0s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes headercolors {
    from {
        background-position:0 bottom;
    }
    to {
        background-position:1600px bottom;
    }
}

@keyframes headercolors {
    from {
        background-position:0 bottom;
    }
    to {
        background-position:1600px bottom;
    }
}
```

Basically the gradient background is treated as an image and you can simple move it by using background-position.

Comment: Thank you. I realized both solutions work on Chrome but not on my Firefox. Derp.

Comment: Mozilla use the -moz-linear-gradient. This is what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/89BuE/5/

Comment: Nice one ! A simple tweak of using an integer multiple value of div width instead of fixed 1600 would make it even smoother (the repeat loop / restart will not be visible anymore). This can be achieved a little bit harder if your design is responsive (widths are changing) ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a background image larger than the width, and then animate the position

CSS

```
#header-colors {
    animation-direction: reverse;
    animation: header-colors infinite 15s linear;
    -webkit-animation: header-colors infinite 15s linear;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #f5aa00 0px, #f5aa00 12.5%, #55c5e9 12.5%, #55c5e9 25%, #6b3a78 25%, #6b3a78 37.5%, #9e1c32 37.5%, #9e1c32 50%, #0768bf 50%, #0768bf 62.5%, #629db1 62.5%, #629db1 75%, #f5aa00 75%, #f5aa00 87.5%, #55c5e9 87.5%, #55c5e9 100%);
    background-size: 200% auto;
    height: 20px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}


@-webkit-keyframes header-colors {
    0% {background-position-x: 0%;}
   100% {background-position-x: 100%;}
}

@keyframes header-colors {
    0% {background-position-x: 0%;}
   100% {background-position-x: 100%;}
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Pwxpc/)

Note: right now, it will *jump* at the end of the animation. To avoid that, you need to set 2 identical cycles of the color strips in the background image (so that one part overlaps the other at th end of the animation

In Firefox, background-position-x is not working. change this to make it work

```
@keyframes header-colors {
    0% {background-position: 0% 0px;}
  100% {background-position: 100% 0px;}
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated. Something screws up the animation on my Firefox but it works good on Chrome. Thank you.